# FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL regex to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need to make email validation on client side same with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL. So what would be the equivalent regex on javascript with the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL?

I found that FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL regex is from here: http://squiloople.com/2009/12/20/email-address-validation/ but when I tried to copy paste the regex to javascript I get `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /#<error>/: Invalid group`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: @SolracRagnarockradio yes but is it the same with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL? I don't want the email to pass one validation and fail on another.

Comment: That forum entry you link is from 2009 and never claims to show the validation used by PHP. Actual expression can be found at [logical_filters.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L503).

Comment: [mpyw/FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.js: JavaScript Email validation compatible with PHP's filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)](https://github.com/mpyw/FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.js)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to edit my previous comment. Of course we wont validate DNS resolution, MTA precense or IP, but you can check a "string" with this one and it does a pretty good job:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

This is the reference: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29